# How to get designer gradient color QR from phpqrcode

Tags: php

I am trying to get a designer and attractive qrcode generated from php but its not giving output
This is the code. I have tried using this piece of code with styling the qr code but when I run this file its not giving output on browser its only giving a white small rectangle box

```
<?php
include 'phpqrcode/qrlib.php';


$qrtext = 'Gourav';


$qrsize = 10;
ob_start(); 
QRcode::png($qrtext, false, QR_ECLEVEL_L, $qrsize, 2);
$qrcodeimg = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean(); 


$qrcodeimg = imagecreatefromstring($qrcodeimg);


$color1 = imagecolorallocate($qrcodeimg, 0, 0, 255); 
$color2 = imagecolorallocate($qrcodeimg, 0, 255, 255); 


$gradientimg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($qrcodeimg), imagesy($qrcodeimg));
$width = imagesx($gradientimg);
$height = imagesy($gradientimg);
for ($i = 0; $i < $width; $i++) {
    $r = (($i * ($color2 >> 16 & 0xFF) + ($width - $i) * ($color1 >> 16 & 0xFF)) / $width) & 0xFF;
    $g = (($i * ($color2 >> 8 & 0xFF) + ($width - $i) * ($color1 >> 8 & 0xFF)) / $width) & 0xFF;
    $b = (($i * ($color2 & 0xFF) + ($width - $i) * ($color1 & 0xFF)) / $width) & 0xFF;
    $color = imagecolorallocate($gradientimg, $r, $g, $b);
    imageline($gradientimg, $i, 0, $i, $height, $color);
}


imagecopyresampled($qrcodeimg, $gradientimg, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($qrcodeimg), imagesy($qrcodeimg), imagesx($gradientimg), imagesy($gradientimg));


header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($qrcodeimg);

imagedestroy($qrcodeimg);
imagedestroy($gradientimg);
?>
```

Comment: When if try to look up the package you're using, I find this one: https://github.com/t0k4rt/phpqrcode It says: `## DEPRECATED ## Please do not use this QR code library anymore, This library has not been maintained for a long time and should be considered insecure`. Are you using this, or something else?

Comment: i am using same

Comment: The suggestion is that you should look for something else.

Comment: Okh it will be helpful if you suggest me some other libraries which can generate QR code just like telegram QR code

Comment: Recommendations are off-topic here - see the [help/on-topic], and besides I'm sure you can find PHP-based QR code generators using a search engine without much trouble...it shouldn't be something where you need other people to google it for you

Comment: I don't have a suggestion ready, sorry.